AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'. How to fix?
Error:
Internal Server Error: /posts/v3ttel/44/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\posts\views.py", line 140, in post_view
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 112, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 112, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 208, in render
    return template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 177, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py", line 112, in instrumented_test_render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 321, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1064, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 742, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "B:\TEST2_2\ya_02_zad_free\Users\templatetags\user_filters.py", line 9, in addclass
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"class": css})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'as_widget'

forms:
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    fields = ['text']
    labels = {'text': 'Добавить комментарий'}
    help_texts = {'text': 'Текст комментария'}
    widgets = {
        'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'your-css-class', 'cols': 80, 'rows': 5})  
    }

Models:
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
text = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField("date published", auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.text

Views:
@login_required
def add_comment(request, username, post_id):
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id, author__username=username)
   if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.author = request.user
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('post', username=username, post_id=post_id)
else:
    form = CommentForm()

return render(request, 'comments.html', {'form': form, 'post': post})

Filter:
@register.filter 
def addclass(field, css):
    return field.as_widget(attrs={"class": css})

{% include 'comments.html' %}
{{ form.text|addclass:"form-control" }}

How to fix it?

Can you try adding a comma after text? So fields = ['text', ]
